# Page number in PowerPoint slide not appearing

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint-2007

I try to add a page number in PowerPoint 2007, but it doesn't appear.

I go to Insert » Slide Number, tick the "Slide Number", and then apply to all. Nothing happens, and if I reopen the slide number option, it is still unticked.

Answer (score 5):

Try Viewing your Master and then inserting the page number

1. View > Slide Master
2. Insert > Header & Footer > Slide Number (going through Header & Footer alone might be your solution)
3. Check Slide number
4. Apply to All